# Rgd usage of latest version of elsa3.0 in our production grade application

Tags: elsa-workflows

what is the plan for an official release of Elsa 3?

From which minor version of Elsa3.0  we can start using it in our production grade applications. As i understand this is completely re-written of 2.0 version , our application will break if we start with Elsa2.0 and move to Elsa3.0